# Getting Google Cloud SDK site online

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

So I've been following Udacity's Web Development Course(CS253) and I managed to follow along up until Lesson 2's Problem Set. The instructor basically tells you to create a website that uses ROT13 to convert the input the user gives in a HTML form(Hello becomes Urryb for instance. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMGNwoFHfB4 this is the Youtube video if it helps). Now the problem was, I had managed to create the function to convert the input, and I had created the layout of the website, but I could not figure out how to get the input the user was providing in the HTML form and store it in a variable so that I could convert it.Since I am using Python,I checked the forum and found out I had to use something called CGI. I tried to use it but my site is hosted locally(I'm accessing it through localhost on my browser), and the guy who posted the answer said the site should be hosted online. My question is, how would I get the site online? I already have another site hosted on a free host(Hostinger) but it only uses HTML and CSS, without needing the Google Cloud SDK. To start the Google Cloud site I have to open CMD, navigate to the folder where my main.py is and type "dev_appserver.py app.yaml". How would I do this on the host?Moreover, how would I install the Google Cloud SDK on the host? This is my MainPage handler if it helps:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.write('''
    <h1>ROT13 Generator</h1>
    <form  method="post">
        <input type="text" name="htmlUserInput" size="30" >
    </form>
        ''');

def post(self):
    form =cgi.FieldStorage(); # equals to none
    userInput=form.getvalue('htmlUserInput'); # equals to none
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at Cloud SDK? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Comment: As a relative newbie to the world of web dev, I'm kinda overwhelmed by everything there and was hoping someone could explain to me how to do it, or point me to a tutorial(if there is any).

Comment: Got you. I'm currently lacking the time to explain, so I'll just help you by upvoting so this question grabs some attention. Hopefully someone will write/point to a simple step-by-step tutorial. Believe me, when it comes to Google Cloud, it's a bit complicated, so a tutorial will be great.

Comment: Thank you! And yeah, a tutorial/explanation would be awesome.

Comment: AppEngine is built to run on google infrastructure.  You usually deploy the application using [`appcfg.py`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp), or using the `gcloud` sdk (both are shown in the link).  They have a free trial (and free tiers if you aren't using much -- which you won't be for this project I don't think).  There are projects which aim to port the GAE runtime to other infrastructures (AppScale comes to mind), but I don't know how advanced they are, or how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend going through the [Guestbook tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/creating-guestbook)

It will [explain what to put in app.yaml and your main WSGI script](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/handling-user-input-form).

Then it will show how to [deploy to Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/deploying-the-application).

I recommend not jumping straight to the deploy part because you will need to create the files in the other steps.

You will at least need an `app.yaml` like:

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: python_script_file_name.app
```

Replacing `python_script_file_name` with whatever your Python file name is.

And you should add the following code to your Python code:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Although you will want to use `debug=False` if you expand this site further and put it into "production".

Comment: Sorry mate, didn't log on my account for a while. Thank you for the answer.